# Is mx.containers.HDividedBox deprecated in Flex 4.5?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex4.5, mxml, flex-spark

Is mx.containers.HDividedBox deprecated by some spark container in Flex 4.5?

I'm new to Flex programming and can't find any spark replacement for it.

I want to have 2 Lists separated by movable vertical bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no any Spark replacement of `mx.containers.HDividedBox` for now. So you can use it without any problem. And it is not officially deprecated for now.